# Sample color calculation in rotated grid supersampling

Tags: antialiasing, subpixel-rendering, supersampling

I'm rendering a scene using scanline method. In order to get rid of aliasing we need to render a scene with higher resolution (2x, for example). I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the color of a sample when it is not taken from the center of the subpixel. For example, we have 4 subpixels per 1 pixel, where the blue circle is the center of the subpixel, and the red circle is the sample position.

[image]

I tried to find information about sample calculation, but got nothing. I assume that I need to calculate sample color using 4 neighboring subpixels and apply bilinear interpolation to them to find the color.

[image]

Is my guess true, or does it have to somehow calculate the color of the sample in a different way?

Comment: What are the samples and subpixels in this context? Are you ray-tracing, sampling a texture, or something else entirely?

Comment: @DanHulme I'm rendering a scene using scanline method. In order to get rid of aliasing we need to render a scene with higher resolution (2x, for example). After that we have 4 subpixels per 1 pixel. As I know, the easiest way to downsample a frame is to calculate the average color of all subpixels (regular grid algorithm?). But I can't figure out how to calculate the color of a sample which is not positioned in the center of subpixel. I think that it's calculated using 4 neighbouring subpixels,but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PaviełKraskoŭski i need any tutorial to understand this problem

Comment: @x-rw [Here](https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/msaa-overview/) you can read about supersampling at the beginning of the article before "SUPERSAMPLING EVOLVES INTO MSAA". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling). [Link](https://www.everything2.com/index.pl?node_id=1028947) on the Wikipedia page to the reference article.